# How to specify the difference between client controller vs server controller action in Lightning?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I ran into an issue where my code was stuck in a loop, because I was calling this from a controller action:  `onclick="{!c.saveAccount}"`.

This in turned called a client-side controller action:

```
saveAccount: function(component, event, helper) {
    // ...
    var action = component.get("c.saveAccount");
    // ...
    $A.enqueueAction(action); 
}
```

On the server-side, there's a controller action, `saveAccount(Account)`. What ended up happening is my client-side controller action kept calling itself, because I assume `component.get("c.saveAccount")` is a reference to the client side controller action, and not the server-side controller action.

The way I stopped it was create a `saveAccount` helper method, and rename the client-side controller action to `handleSaveAccount`.

So, am I correct in assume that both client-side and server-side controller actions have to be unambiguous? That is, I cannot have a client-side and server-side controller action with the same name?

Are there any established best practices or patterns to ensure a clear differentiation between client-side and server-side controller actions?

Answer (score 8):

Client side and server side controller method name should not be the same its documented [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_actions_call.htm)

> Use unique names for client-side and server-side actions in a
>   component. A JavaScript function (client-side action) with the same
>   name as an Apex method (server-side action ) can lead to hard-to-debug
>   issues. In debug mode, the framework logs a browser console warning
>   about the clashing client-side and server-side action names.

Regarding naming convention, we keep the client side controller and helper  method same in lightning component bundle and for apex methods we start with `'callTo'` + functional purpose : `'getlstaccounts' or 'updateProfile'` to follow a consistent naming pattern.